# Using parametric equations to form a line equation from two points

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric

In order to form a line equation from two points I have been told to do following and not to use any other ways.

$$a(9,6) \qquad b(2,-1)\\
\begin{align}
x&=9-7t\\
y&=6-7t
\end{align}$$

Cancel out the $t$s gives
$$x-y=3$$

but when the signs are opposite I don't know what to do such as

$$a(7,6) \qquad b(8,1)\\
\begin{align}
x&=7+1t\\
y&=6-5t
\end{align}$$

and also

$$a(-1,-2) \qquad b(7,-3)\\
\begin{align}
x&=-1+8t\\
y&=-2-1t
\end{align}$$

I with some could show me how to work these questions out in this format so I have a reference I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The equation $x=7+t$ holds exactly for the same $x$ and $t$ when $5x=35+5t$.

Comment: how could i not see that you have multiplied x=7+t by 5, and as y=6-5t they cancel each other out. right?